# Image will not save with Paperclip and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to use Paperclip for uploading an image for an has many and belongs to relationship with 'pictures'

I'm certain that imagemagick etc, is correctly installed, because i've more image uploaders in this project that works, difference is that this one has an has many relation.

I'm not getting a 'Saving Attachment' in the console. So my idea is that this is completely ignored by the strong parameters.

In topicscontroller:

```
params.require(:topic).permit(:id, :title, :content, :active, pictures_attributes: [:image, :id, :_destroy] )
```

In Topic Model:

```
has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
validates :title, :content, presence: true
```

In Picture Model:

```
belongs_to :topic

has_attached_file :image,
:styles => { :medium => "400x400#", :thumb => "200x200#", :small => "50x50#" },
:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png')
```

I know that there are many other topics about this, only all are rails 3 and is different in the way of setting 'attr_accessible'

Comment: Have you tried the [rails-4](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/rails-4) branch of paperclip?

Comment: No, because this must work, because on an other project, this isn't a problem. But i managed to get some errors this time. 
"Unpermitted parameters: title_text, image", this is right: because i'm not stricly following the permit params, but without no errors occurs.

"params.require(:topic).permit(:id, :title, :content, :active, pictures_attributes: { picture: [:image, :title_text]} )", I've tried all ways, but the correct one i guess ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 3.5.0 of Paperclip, everything is fine for Rails 4.